# How to deal with "This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Tags: java, exception

Error message:This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.

Here shows a java program:

```
class err1 extends Exception {}

class Obj1 {
    Obj1() throws err1 {
        throw new err1();
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[]argv) {
        Class a[] = {Obj1.class};
        try {
            a[0].newInstance();
        } catch(err1 e) { //Here meet my error
        }
    }
}
```

What shall I do to deal it?
Not to tell me to replace `catch(err1 e)` to `catch(Exception e)`, for my Eclipse doesn't know a Exception can be thrown.

In addition,when I launch it,things as follows happened.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problem:
Unreachable catch block for err1. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

then I suddenly knew what I shall do...

Comment: include another `catch` block after the previous one until all exceptions are caught. If you are using a higher java version you could also use a multicatch block.

Comment: How to deal with it? Don't try to catch exceptions which will not be thrown by your code in the `try` block (at least the compiler couldn't find it).

Comment: Can you please indent code properly if you are asking for people's help?

Comment: The exception of type `err1` is never thrown by `.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflective method `newInstance()`, throws, amongst other things, `InstantiationException`. This will be thrown if an exception of any type is encountered in a constructor. You need to catch that one, and abstract your `err1` using appropriate methods in the `InstantiationException` class.

`newInstance()` does not know about your specific exception per se, but rather it encapsulates it in the `InstantiationException`.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception type is not known at compile time, since anything could be contained inside the Class array.

What you could do is check for the type in the catch block:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class a[] = {Obj1.class};
        try {
            a[0].newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof CustomException) {
                System.out.println("CustomException");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Obj1 {
    Obj1() throws CustomException {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}

class CustomException extends Exception {

}
```

Can't resist to mention: It is very helpful to others if you adhere to generally accepted coding/naming/formatting conventions.

Comment: Excuse me but I'd like to tell you that when I launch my program things as follows will happen:The program executes safely until the try statement body and jvm exits,leaving these words:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:Unresolved compilation problem:
Unreachable catch block for err1. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body